# php excel installation gives error

Tags: 12.04, installation

I need to install `php excel writer (PHPExcel)` in my machine running Ubuntu 12.04. But I don't know what steps I need to follow.

How can I install it?

I have tried

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.pearplex.net
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Discovering channel pear.pearplex.net over http:// failed with message: channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.pearplex.net/channel.xml" (File http://pear.pearplex.net:80/channel.xml not valid (redirected but no location))
Trying to discover channel pear.pearplex.net over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.pearplex.net" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.pearplex.net/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.pearplex.net:443' failed: ))
```

Comment: are you digging something with PHP ? All the best. this is the 2nd Q from you today

Comment: ya I had this problem earlier as well.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and paste these commands

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.pearplex.net
sudo pear install pearplex/PHPExcel
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier as well it gives error. I have edited my question.